# cURL and URL refresh after POST/Login

Tags: php, post, curl, page-refresh

I am attempting to create a PHP script that will login to a website, use the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to return the URL information after login and then parse this data for specific matches. I would like to know if there is a way to refresh the returntransfer data without having to logout and log back into the site? As of now, I have to log out completely and then login to get the new http string in returntransfer. I am new to PHP and cURL, so please forgive me if this question is vague. Below is the sample code, as you can see, based on the flag, the code will continue to loop until flag is set to true.

```
<?php


 if(isset($_POST['userName']))
     {


       $cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";     
       $data = array('Username' => $_POST['userName'],'Password' =>$_POST['userPassword']);
       $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7";
       $reffer = "https://someurl/Login.aspx?action=login";
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://someurl/Login.aspx?action=login");   
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_fie_path);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,$reffer);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
       $html= curl_exec($ch);

       echo $html; 

       curl_close($ch);

       $flagOfFound=0;
       do {
       //process the message

       //......
       //set $flagOfFound = true of there is match
       //else
       //refresh message/http returntransfer while still logged in

       }           
       while ($flagOfFound == 0);

     }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> without having to logout and log back into the site

Just don't keep/store any cookie when you do these requests.

Remove these line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_fie_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
```

that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Federico. If I don't keep cookies, when I refresh the .asp page, won't I be logged out automatically, and thus have to log back in? What this script is really trying to do is parse through the http data and search for certain URLs, which it will then select for the user that is logged in.